# Share private data and prevent data forwarding

Tags: private-blockchain, storage, privacy

Let's say A has some private medical records of patients and B is a pharmaceutical company who wants to view medical records from A to find out the effect of a particular drug on the patients (run a drug evaluation logic to get performance statistics of a particular drug). A wants to share the private data to B but wants to prevent B to forward (leak) the data to other organizations.  How can this problem be solved with blockchain?

Comment: This question has been flagged as off-topic, but it would be interesting to see the answer in the context of Ethereum.

Comment: B only needs the data to run his evaluation logic, thus can B's logic be included in a smart contract where the read permission of the data can be given to the evaluation logic function? By this way, B can only see the output of the evaluation logic without getting exposure of the data. Is this possible?